# Getting around cookie dot rule to change value via Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I'm working on a drop-in script for a site whose existing code I cannot modify.

I need to change the value of a cookie via Javascript, but the cookie dot rule is giving me trouble.

The existing cookie (which I cannot do anything about) has a domain of "www.example.com".

I tried to set a replacement cookie with the same domain, but when I inspect the cookies on the page, I see that my replacement cookie has a domain of ".www.example.com" and the cookie I had intended to replace is not only still there, but is apparently overruling the replacement cookie.

Deleting the existing cookie entirely might work, if it weren't for the fact that the cookie gets re-set if removed (which I cannot do anything about).

Any suggestions for how I can replace the existing cookie?

Comment: Why you get this `.` before `www`?

Answer (score 0):

This is nasty, but in JavaScript last function wins.

Assuming there is function `setCookies` you have no access to it code:

```
function setCookies() {
    // code that make you crazy
}
```

After that load file with your function:

```
function setCookies() {
    // code that make you crazy
    // + some modification
}
```

Copy entire code from original `setCookie` function to new function with the same name and apply your modification.